# Can someone optimize my .net RegEx for Powershell - parsing a table with errors

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, parsing

Currently I am trying to parse a table from a Microsoft Site (the GitHub Version of it) to get proper PowerShell Objects. I'll share the relevant code part so you can test it. It does parse what i want but i want the results to be already trimmed (no leading trailing spaces or line-breaks). I also have to get the result for **"CNG Key Isolation"** which has a different formatting. Only for that block of data my RegEx includes line breaks and I did not get it to work. I know I could do some parsing in PowerShell after the RegEx, but I want to get better with RegEx.

My not yet optimized RegEx looks like this

```
(?:^##\s*(?<ServiceTitle>[^\r\n#]*)[\r\n\s]*\|\s+Name\s+\|\s+Description\s+\|(?:[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Service name[\|\*\s]+(?<ServiceName>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Description[\|\*\s]+(?<Description>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Installation[\|\*\s]+(?<Installation>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Startup type[\|\*\s]+(?<StartupType>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Recommendation[\|\*\s]+(?<Recommendation>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Comments[\|\*\s]+(?<Comments>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|))*)
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/xQDRCO/1

The data to parse comes from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/main/WindowsServerDocs/security/windows-services/security-guidelines-for-disabling-system-services-in-windows-server.md

It should basically take one block of data for each service and try to get

```
"ServiceTitle","ServiceName","Description","Installation","StartupType","Recommendation","Comments"
```

No matter what order they are or if one of them is missing. **"ServiceTitle"** is something special and has to be there.

Here is the PowerShell code I currently tested:

```
$fields = "ServiceTitle","ServiceName","Description","Installation","StartupType","Recommendation","Comments"
$RequestData = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/main/WindowsServerDocs/security/windows-services/security-guidelines-for-disabling-system-services-in-windows-server.md
$RegExMatches = [Regex]::Matches($RequestData.content,'(?:^##\s*(?<ServiceTitle>[^\r\n#]*)[\r\n\s]*\|\s+Name\s+\|\s+Description\s+\|(?:[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Service name[\|\*\s]+(?<ServiceName>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Description[\|\*\s]+(?<Description>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Installation[\|\*\s]+(?<Installation>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Startup type[\|\*\s]+(?<StartupType>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Recommendation[\|\*\s]+(?<Recommendation>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|)|[\r\n\s\|\-\*]+Comments[\|\*\s]+(?<Comments>[^\|]*?)(?: ?\|))*)',[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)
$FullList = @()
foreach ($entry in $RegExMatches) {$ServiceAsObject = [pscustomobject]@{};foreach ($field in $fields) {$ServiceAsObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $field -Value $entry.Groups[$field].value};$FullList += $ServiceAsObject}
$FullList[15..17] # three items to see what problem i have with "CNG Key Isolation"
```

I am not using larger RegEx like that one often, so feel free to give me some feedback to improve myself.

Thank you,
An-Dir

Comment: What PowerShell version do you use? As of version 7.1 there is [ConvertFrom-Markdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-markdown) you could use

Comment: @Theo Looks like `ConvertFrom-Markdown` only output HTML or VT100-escaped tabular output, no option for getting a custom object or dictionary back :-/

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Hmmm yes, I see what you mean. I should have ended my comment with a questionmark  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be what you are looking for, but you could do something like the following to output an array of custom objects:

```
$output = switch -regex ($requestdata.content -split '\r?\n') {
    '^##\s' {
        # tracking empty lines since there is one under the service title
        # start new hash table when a new service is found
        # remove ## from service title names
        $emptyLineCount = 0
        $hash = [ordered]@{}
        $hash.ServiceTitle = $_ -replace '^##\s'
    }
    '\| \*\*' {
        # split on | and surrounding spaces
        # replace ** so name is cleaner
        if ($hash.ServiceTitle) {
            $key,$value = ($_ -split '\s*\|\s*' -replace '\*\*')[1,2]
            $hash[$key] = $value
        }
    }
    '^$' {
        # when second empty line is reached in a service block, output object
        if ($hash.ServiceTitle -and ++$emptyLineCount -eq 2) {
            [pscustomobject]$hash
        }
    }
}

# Finding a service by title
$output | Where ServiceTitle -eq 'CNG Key Isolation'
```

Splitting the contents makes an array of lines, which is easier for me to use `switch` statement.

---

Using a purer regex solution will make things more brittle if there are data inconsistencies. The data block for CNG Key Isolation is missing the  `|` at the end of each line and is the only one like that. So now you have to match that special case or fix the data.

```
$fields = "ServiceTitle","ServiceName","Description","Installation","StartupType","Recommendation","Comments"
$RequestData = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/main/WindowsServerDocs/security/windows-services/security-guidelines-for-disabling-system-services-in-windows-server.md
$regexString = '(?m)^##\s(?<ServiceTitle>.*)$(?s).*?\*\*Service name\*\* \| (?<ServiceName>.*?(?=\s+\|)).*?\*\*Description\*\* \| (?<Description>.*?(?=\s+\|)).*?\*\*Installation\*\* \| (?<Installation>.*?(?=\s+\|)).*?\*\*Startup type\*\* \| (?<StartupType>.*?(?=\s+\|)).*?\*\*Recommendation\*\* \| (?<Recommendation>.*?(?=\s+\|)).*?\*\*Comments\*\* \| (?<Comments>.*?(?=\s+\|))'
$out = $RequestData.Content |
    Select-String -Pattern $regexString -AllMatches |
        Foreach-Object { $_.Matches | Foreach-Object {
            $hash = [ordered]@{}
            foreach ($field in $fields) {
                $hash.$field = $_.Groups.where{$_.Name -eq $field}.Value}
                [pscustomobject]$hash
            }
        }
```

Comment: it throws me "Cannot index into a null array" errors "$hash[$key] = $value". But in general it seems to work and thats a very nice idea and i like it very much. it is a stable solution if no other "^##\s" line comes before the tables and it is not very prone to errors. +1. Tried measure command, and your solution is 3-4 times faster than mine is atm. But to improve my regEx skills i would be happy if someone tried to find a solution to fix my regex.

Comment: @An-dir I fixed those errors.

Comment: @An-dir I added a regex match for the entire string.

Comment: Like your solution very very very much <3, and it works in PowerShell as expected. It's pretty and clean. Can you tell me if you have any regEx (online)tester that is able to show this correctly or did you just do this all without highlighting in pure PowerShell? Because of a missing tool like regex101.com, but good for complex powershell/.net regex, i would never have found that kind of solution.

Comment: I just looked at the data and wrote it out in Powershell. I think regex101 is a fine tool. However Powershell allows some regex things that other engines don’t. For example, Powershell allows non-fixed lengths in lookarounds. I don’t think regex101 allows that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all that text in your `$RequestData.content`, then I wouldn't try to create one large regex to parse it all out into usable objects, but instead would do:

```
# first split the tables from the rest of the text and work on the table lines only
$result = ($RequestData.content -split '(?m)^The following tables.*:')[-1].Trim() -split '(?m)^## ' | 
    Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } |
    ForEach-Object {
        # split each block to parse out the title and the table data
        $title, $table = ($_.Trim() -split '(\r?\n){2}', 2).Trim()
        # now remove the markdown stuff from the data and convert it using ConvertFrom-Csv
        $data = (($table -replace '(?m)^\|--\|--\||[*]{2}|^\||\|$' -replace '\s\|\s', '|') -split '\r?\n' -ne '').Trim()  | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'
        # set up an ordered Hashtable to store the data
        $hash = [ordered]@{ServiceTitle = $title}
        foreach ($item in $data) {
            $hash[$item.Name] = $item.Description
        }
        # output real objects
        [PsCustomObject]$hash
    }

$result
```

Comment: Normally i would have made something like that but that solution has one major problem. if the first key sentence "The following tables" was changed it wont work anymore

Comment: @An-dir Well... since this documentation hasn't changed since 11/26/2018 and it is all about Windows Server 2016,  I don't think this line will change anytime soon.. Maybe in newer documentation for newer server versions you need to redefine the part where you can split between the blahblah and the actual tables, but that would be an easy adjustment then.